# ASP.NET Core 2.2 - How to clear a textarea with data from SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a textarea on my ASP.NET Core webform which I use for receiving messages through SignalR.

I have a Clear button underneath in which I use a js script at the bottom of the Razor page to clear the textarea on demand. Weird thing is if I have any data displayed from a SingalR message bound to the textarea, the Clear button will not clear the textarea unless I manually type something in as well.

If there is no data displayed in the texarea from a SignalR message then I can clear the textarea with any manually typed text OK.

It seems the textarea does not know there is any data/text held within textarea until I manually type something in first.

Reference to the screeshot below: The first two lines are messages I generated through SignalR, the remaining lines of text are manually typed into the textarea by myself.

[image: screenshot]

Razor Page:

```
 <div class="row" style="margin-top: 1em">
    <div class="col">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Inbound Events"</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="20" id="inboundTextArea" oninput="countCharInbound(this)"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 1em">
    <div class="col-md-auto col-sm-auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="eraseTextInbound();">
            Clear Window
            <i class="fas fa-broom"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="mb-2  mb-md-0"></div>
    </div>
```

JS Script at the bottom of the razor page:

```
 <script>
// Clear Textarea button Inbound.
function eraseTextInbound() {
    document.getElementById("inboundTextArea").value = "";
}
// Clear Textarea button Outbound.
function eraseTextOutbound() {
    document.getElementById("outboundTextArea").value = "";
}
// When textarea reached x no. chars, clear text.
function countCharInbound(val) {
    var len = val.value.length;
    if (len >= 1000) {
        document.getElementById("inboundTextArea").value = "";
    }
}
// When textarea reached x no. chars, clear text.
function countCharOutbound(val) {
    var len = val.value.length;
    if (len >= 1000) {
        document.getElementById("outboundTextArea").value = "";
    }
}
```

JS Script extract from a seperate js file that I use for the SignalR script:

```
 // Send Message Function.
 // Used for displaying System Events onto the webpage.
 connection.on("Send", function (message) {
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.textContent = message;
document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li); // Events received area on web page
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that the data from a SignalR message is the chat message received from another people?I tested a demo with your code ,but it seems to be no problem .It would be better that you share the more details or code to help reproduce the issue .

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question with a screenshot and included the js function that binds the SignalR message to the textarea. Hope this helps, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the id of the element that you want to clear in the `eraseTextInbound` function is not the id of the element which the SignalR message is binded to .

From the SignalR script you provided ,the id of the element that shows the SignalR message is `messagesList` not `inboundTextArea`.

- If you want to bind the SignalR message to the textarea,  you could
  try to change js function like below :

  ```
  connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
   var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
   var encodedMsg = user + " says " + msg;
   document.getElementById("inboundTextArea").value = encodedMsg;
  });
  ```
- Or add the below code in the `eraseTextInbound` function to clear the SignalR message that is binded to the element with the id `messagesList`

  ```
   function eraseTextInbound() {
          document.getElementById("inboundTextArea").value = "";
          document.getElementById("messagesList").innerHTML = "";
      }
  ```

The complete code of the razor page

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-6">
        User..........<input type="text" id="userInput" />
        <br />
        Message...<input type="text" id="messageInput" />
        <input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send Message" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <hr />
        </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <ul id="messagesList"></ul>
            </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="margin-top: 1em">
    <div class="col">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Inbound Events"</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="20" id="inboundTextArea" oninput="countCharInbound(this)">

        </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 1em">
    <div class="col-md-auto col-sm-auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="eraseTextInbound();">
            Clear Window
            <i class="fas fa-broom"></i>
        </button>
    <div class="mb-2  mb-md-0"></div>
</div>
</div>

    <script src="~/lib/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>

    <script>
        // Clear Textarea button Inbound.
        function eraseTextInbound() {
            document.getElementById("inboundTextArea").value = "";
            document.getElementById("messagesList").innerHTML = "";
        }
        // When textarea reached x no. chars, clear text.
        function countCharInbound(val) {
            var len = val.value.length;
            if (len >= 1000) {
                document.getElementById("inboundTextArea").value = "";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

[Here](https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/v-xuelc_microsoft_com/EU946a_0N5RLnZIDDkvzCB8BjaawOXj0I4ctaN85p978XQ?e=kA8OpF) is my simple project , you could refer to.

Comment: Hi Xueli, The key part to your solution was to add another line to the function which clears the innerHTML as well as setting the value to "". I think I also had some of my functions and code a little mixed while trying different things. Thank you so much for your efforts in helping me :)